Start Chrome with device emulation (iPhone 12 Pro) from a script in Windows
I use Google Chrome with Internet to run automated tests and I would like to know if there is a way to launch Chrome in emulation mode.
For example:

I tried a workaround with the --emulation-mode="iPhone 12 Pro" flag and with a custom userAgent but it's producing nothing. Maybe some other flags would help me?
